# Покраска значков spinner и menu

Tags: android-studio, android-sdk

Не вижу истины, понимаю, что она рядом, но не вижу. Как на > 21 API покрасить выделенные элементы в белый?)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: < 21 API, вернее

Comment: У меня была такая проблема и я решил ее, изменив тему активити. Нужна темная тема, тогда все иконки станут белыми, если я не путаю. Сам еще новичок)

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте задать цвет в атрибуте `colorControlNormal` в стилях приложения (`res/values/styles.xml`)

```
<item name="colorControlNormal">#FF0000</item>
```